# MarkLogic DHF 5.2.1 QuickStart - Local Setup - Flow not found

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I tried to setup DHF 5.2.1 after upgrading from ML9 to ML10 in my local. QuickStart Setup was smooth and I created an entity and flow as well. When I ran the flow, I got the below error:

*Local message: Could not apply resource at documents. Server Message: The specified flow GradeIngestionFlow is missing.*

GradeIngestionFlow is my flow name. I tried to use the option "REDEPLOY" on flows tab and ran after that and still got the same error. I could also see the flow under 'C:\DHF\flows'. Below is the full error log from JOBS DB. Can someone help in debugging this error?

```
{
"job": {
"jobId": "0f6dfb8b-b3b3-437c-b500-65327aae775d", 
"flow": "GradeIngestionFlow", 
"user": "joshi", 
"lastAttemptedStep": "1", 
"lastCompletedStep": 0, 
"jobStatus": "failed", 
"timeStarted": "2020-05-17T01:21:11.8611683+05:30", 
"timeEnded": "2020-05-17T01:21:12.8723422+05:30", 
"stepResponses": {
"1": {
"flowName": "GradeIngestionFlow", 
"stepName": "GradeIngestionStep", 
"stepDefinitionName": "default-ingestion", 
"stepDefinitionType": "ingestion", 
"stepOutput": [
"Local message: Could not apply resource at documents. Server Message: The specified flow GradeIngestionFlow is missing."
], 
"fullOutput": null, 
"status": "failed step 1", 
"totalEvents": 16, 
"successfulEvents": 0, 
"failedEvents": 16, 
"successfulBatches": 0, 
"failedBatches": 1, 
"success": false, 
"stepStartTime": "2020-05-17T01:21:12.4422097+05:30", 
"stepEndTime": "2020-05-17T01:21:12.8335275+05:30"
}
}
}
}
```

I'm yet to try setting up using gradle.

[image: Entities & Flows Structure]

Contents of json file:

```
{
  "name" : "GradeIngestionFlow",
  "description" : "Grade inegsiton",
  "batchSize" : 100,
  "threadCount" : 4,
  "stopOnError" : false,
  "options" : { },
  "version" : 0,
  "steps" : {
    "1" : {
      "name" : "GradeIngestionStep",
      "description" : "Grade Ingestion",
      "options" : {
        "additionalCollections" : [ ],
        "headers" : {
          "sources" : [ {
            "name" : "GradeIngestionFlow"
          } ],
          "createdOn" : "currentDateTime",
          "createdBy" : "currentUser"
        },
        "sourceQuery" : "cts.collectionQuery([])",
        "collections" : [ "GradeIngestionStep" ],
        "permissions" : "data-hub-operator,read,data-hub-operator,update",
        "outputFormat" : "xml",
        "targetDatabase" : "data-hub-STAGING"
      },
      "customHook" : {
        "module" : "",
        "parameters" : { },
        "user" : "",
        "runBefore" : false
      },
      "retryLimit" : null,
      "batchSize" : 100,
      "threadCount" : 4,
      "stepDefinitionName" : "default-ingestion",
      "stepDefinitionType" : "INGESTION",
      "fileLocations" : {
        "inputFilePath" : "C:\\Users\\Joshi\\DHF\\Ingestion",
        "inputFileType" : "csv",
        "outputURIReplacement" : "",
        "separator" : ","
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: **---** Can you describe your Gradle command with all the parameters ?  **---** Would you mind sharing  **entites** , **flows** expanded structures and the content of `GradeIngestionFlow.flow.json` ?

Comment: 1. I did this setup using QuickStart. No gradle command. 2. Expanded Structure: Attached in the question (edited) 3. Contents of json: Added in question (edited)